# Fill 1D Array Using Permutation of 1D Array

Tags: c, random

My goal is to create a two-dimensional array, which will be filled using a random permutation of a one-dimensional array. The first row and column of `tab` should not be filled. This is what I have tried so far, which doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define S 5

void make_board(char tab[S][S]){
    int i;
    int j;
    char signs[16] = {'Z', 'Z', 'Y','Y','X','X','W','W','U', 'U', 'V', 'V', 'S', 'S', 'T', 'T'};

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        int r = ( rand() % 16 );
        int rx = ( rand() % 4 ) + 1;
        int ry = ( rand() % 4 ) + 1;
        tab[rx][ry] = signs[r];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `signs[r]` instead of `r` in `tab[rx][ry] = r;`?

Comment: of course, my mistake, but it still doesnt give me what i need, some fields are always empty, and some have chars i didnt include in my array

Comment: you loops up to 16 only, but field has size 5x5, so you need to cycle from 0 to 25, and rx = rand() % 5; ry = rand() % 5;

Comment: no, i want first column and first row to be empty, its in the description;)

Comment: yeah, missed it. you fill random cells instead of all: rx and ry depend on rand(). you need rx = (i % 4) + 1; ry = (i / 4) + 1; instead rand()

Answer (score 0):

For a permutation, where each `char` in `signs` gets placed in a unique position in `tab`, you need to do a little more work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define S 5
#define C 16

int main()
{
    char signs[C] = {'Z', 'Z', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'W', 'W', 'U', 'U', 'V', 'V', 'S', 'S', 'T', 'T'};
    char tab[S][S];

    srand(time(NULL));

    // generate the random permutation
    size_t perm[C];
    for (int i = 0; i < C; i++)
        perm[i] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < C; i++)
    {
        int j = rand() % C;
        char tmp = signs[j];
        signs[j] = signs[i];
        signs[i] = tmp;
    }

    // copy the chars to tab
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < S; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < S; j++)
        {
            tab[i][j] = signs[perm[k++]];
            printf("%c", tab[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well it's random, so the output will be different every time. Are you saying you don't want any letters to repeat in each row?

Comment: well i want every element of 'signs' to be used only once. its gonna be two times Z, two times Y and so on... and i thought srand is taking care of it

Comment: The `srand` call with the time is what makes the output different every time. Also, I have updated my answer.